# Where are the default file/folder ignore rules for Visual Studio TFS stored?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

When I add a solution to TFS through the Visual Studio 2013 "Add solution to source control" menu option certain (build output) files and folders are automatically ignored.  I know I can create a .tfignore file to customise this behaviour, and that is not what I'm asking about.  Can anyone tell me where the *default* Visual Studio standard exclusion list is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43227500/117965

File is located at `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Configuration\VersionControl\`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a list, Visual Studio just places common Binary files onto the "Excluded" tab. It has been this way since TFS 2010. I don't even think messing with the Team Project Collection's Source Control options for multiple checkouts can help.

If there is a list, I'd guess it is in the registry somewhere.