# What files are ignored in TFS by default?

Tags: tfs

Where can I find the complete list of files ignored by TFS by default (like *.dll, *.log, etc)? I saw it for GIT, but not for a "native" version control. I also saw a lot of links describing how to create your local .tfignore and write there

`# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll`

e.g. [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server), but where can I see already pre-defined list what files will be excluded by TFS if there is no custom .tfignore specified/present on the system?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could refer to the "LocalItemExclusions.config" file under the path `"C:\Users\youraccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Configuration\VersionControl" folder and open"`. 
(There may several folders named like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, you need to make sure open the folder that match your TFS version.)

You could see that these folder and files types are ignored by default and they are defined in that file.

```
      <Exclusion>bin</Exclusion>
      <Exclusion>obj</Exclusion>
      <Exclusion>*.exe</Exclusion>
```

Comment: As I can see from the `LocalItemExclusions.config` there are multiple `TeamProjectCollection/DefaultExclusions` (one for each collection) with `lastDefaultExclusionUpdate` timestamp attribute. This suggests me that there are server defined exclusions. How can I manage them?